# Help with translating a traditional Chinese calligraphy inscription

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

I got a vase with this inscription that I would like some help with translating. I believe it might have been made in the winter year of 1921 (?), but not much else. Is it perhaps possible to find an artists signature? Any help is appreciated.

[image: vase]

Comment: Looks like 辛酉东月志良？？先生雅玩王桉遐敬？. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think it writes 辛酉冬月志良竹翁先生雅玩王枕遐敬赠, which means in the 11th month of 辛酉 year (1981, 1921, 1861, etc) in lunar calendar, 王枕遐 gave this gift to 志良竹翁先生.